# Yii activeRecord how to set the behavior on afterFind?

Tags: php, activerecord, behavior, yii

Yii Active Record how to set the behavior on afterFind?

```
public function afterFind()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [attachBehavior()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent#attachBehavior-detail) to attach a behavior at runtime.